# Given an array of integers, what's the most efficient way to get the number of other integers in the array within n?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, array-map, array-filter

Given the following array:

```
$arr = array(0,0,1,2,2,5,6,7,7,9,10,10);
```

And assuming `$n = 2`, what is the most efficient way to get a count of each value in the array within `$n` of each value?

For example, `6` has 3 other values within `$n`: 5,7,7.

Ultimately I'd like a corresponding array with simply the counts within `$n`, like so:

```
                // 0,0,1,2,2,5,6,7,7,9,10,10 // $arr, so you can see it lined up
$count_arr = array(4,4,4,4,4,3,3,4,4,4, 2, 2);
```

Is a simple foreach loop the way to go? [CodePad Link](http://codepad.org/PpuhcCvG)

```
$arr = array(0,0,1,2,2,5,6,7,7,9,10,10);
$n = 2;
$count_arr = array();
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    $range = range(($v-$n),($v+$n)); // simple range between lower and upper bound
    $count = count(array_intersect($arr,$range)); // count intersect array
    $count_arr[] = $count-1; // subtract 1 so you don't count itself
}
print_r($arr);
print_r($count_arr);
```

Comment: It looks like the array is sorted. Is that always true?

Comment: Not necessarily. But I could always sort beforehand to make it so.

Answer (score 1):

My last answer was written without fully groking the problem...

Try sorting the array, before processing it, and leverage that when you run through it.  This has a better runtime complexity.

```
$arr = array(0,0,1,2,2,5,6,7,7,9,10,10);
asort($arr);
$n = 2;
$cnt = count($arr);
$counts = array_pad(array(), $cnt, 0);
for ($x=0; $x<$cnt; $x++) {
    $low = $x - 1;
    $lower_range_bound = $arr[$x]-$n;
    while($low >= 0 && ($arr[$low] >= $lower_range_bound)) {
        $counts[$x]++;
        $low--;
    }
    $high = $x + 1;
    $upper_range_bound = $arr[$x]+$n;
    while($high < $cnt && $arr[$high] <= $upper_range_bound) {
        $counts[$x]++;
        $high++;
    }
}
print_r($arr);
print_r($counts);
```

Play with it here: http://codepad.org/JXlZNCxW